# Ubuntu server 16.04 won't boot after installation, Fail to start LXD

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, 16.04, lxd

I am new to Ubuntu. Just installed Ubuntu server 16.04 onto Dell R730 server yesterday. The first time reboot was okay. But the server refused to boot today. The error message was: `Failed to start LXD`.

[image: boot messages]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Just searched web. Press Ctrl + Alt + F1,  and it booted successfully. Removed grub and reinstalled grub again. And the problem is gone.

Answer (score 7):

This problem is after upgrade. LXD service needs to be restarted using the root account.

```
sudo service lxd restart
```

You have to reboot afterwards, e.g. using this command:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: No need enter a root shell using `sudo su`. Simply put the `sudo` in front of every single command that needs to be run as root. That way you have the commands logged under your account and you have greater control over what is running with elevated privileges.

Comment: After executing "sudo service lxd restart", it takes so long time to "Starting LXD - main daemon...". Is this normal?

Comment: I encountered this problem after a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 16.04, not an upgrade. Your solution also worked here. Thanks.