# Failed to start LXD

Tags: boot, 16.04, lxd

My server Ubuntu 16.04 cant boot, it show me the text in pink color: FAILED

Then:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start LXD<br/>
See 'systemctl status lxd-containers.service
```

Just like this post: [Ubuntu server 16.04 won't boot after installation, Fail to start LXD](https://askubuntu.com/q/783363/367990)

I tried to vote it, but I don't have the level. So I started a new question.

I have not ssh access to the server, please help :/

Comment: That question you mention got an answer, could you see if it does work?

Comment: Thankyou but too late for me, I reinstalled my system and that fix it, so I can't prove if that solution works, maybe some body else, go and check the link in my question, there are two solutions