# Complete loss of networking in new Ubuntu install

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, raspberrypi

I've been setting up a new install of Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 3. I started with the image from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi), updated and upgraded all packages, upgraded the distro, and upgraded the rPi firmware.

All was going well, but at some point along this path I completely lost my networking. It's hard to say when because I did multiple steps before rebooting.

Since other weird things were happening (booting would sometimes work, sometimes not) I decided to re-pave taking detailed notes of my installation steps along the way. Here they are:

- write base image to SD card
- boot
- change password when instructed during login
- install rpi-update:

  - `sudo curl -L --output /usr/bin/rpi-update https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update/master/rpi-update && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-update`
  - noticed a message "unable to resolve host ubuntu" so added `127.0.0.1 ubuntu` to my /etc/hosts file
- reboot (just to be sure networking is still up)
- run `rpi-update`:

  - `sudo apt-get install binutils`
  - `sudo rpi-update`
- reboot to activate new firmware (and confirm that networking still works)
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade` (85 packages upgraded, around 65MB download)
- reboot

At this point networking no longer works. I noticed these errors in the boot output (taken from */var/log/syslog*):

```
Jul 14 01:18:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LXD - container startup/shutdown...
Jul 14 01:18:34 ubuntu lxd[18312]: error: open /var/lib/lxd/containers: no such file or directory
Jul 14 01:18:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: lxd-containers.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 14 01:18:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LXD - container startup/shutdown.
Jul 14 01:18:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: lxd-containers.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 14 01:18:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: lxd-containers.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
...
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: All rights reserved.
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: All rights reserved.
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: 
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: Cannot find device "eth0"
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: Error getting hardware address for "eth0": No such device
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: Error getting hardware address for "eth0": No such device
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: exiting.
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: 
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu ifup[822]: Failed to bring up eth0.
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: 
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu dhclient[887]: exiting.
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler).
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: cloud-init.service: Job cloud-init.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 14 01:19:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I also now have instability during boot. Sometimes it works, sometimes I get an exception trace with a final message of:

```
Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
```

I've seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783363/ubuntu-server-16-04-wont-boot-after-installation-fail-to-start-lxd) and running `sudo service lxd restart` did fix the LXD issue (after a very long delay), but the networking issue remains.

I've also seen [this](http://pete.akeo.ie/2016/05/help-i-lost-all-networking-on-my.html), which seemed like my exact issue until I tried bringing the misnamed ethernet network up:

```
ifconfig enxb827eb0ecff3 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
sudo ifconfig enxb827eb0ecff3 up
(no output)
sudo ip link set enxb827eb0ecff3 name eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
```

So at this point I'm well and truly out of my depth when it comes to Linux trouble-shooting. Can anyone tell me how to revive networking on my system? And perhaps why this happens in the first place on a fresh install?

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:118400 (118.4 KB)  TX bytes:118400 (118.4 KB)
```

Output of `ifconfig -a`:

```
enxb827eb0ecff3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:0e:cf:f3  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:118400 (118.4 KB)  TX bytes:118400 (118.4 KB)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:5b:9a:a6  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Output of `networkctl`:

```
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           n/a         n/a       
  2 sit0             sit                n/a         n/a       
  3 enxb827eb0ecff3  ether              n/a         n/a       
  4 wlan0            wlan               n/a         n/a       

4 links listed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. If you are Ok with *[Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)* you can simply use the NIC's new name in '/etc/network/interfaces' ...

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Source interfaces
# Please check /etc/network/interfaces.d before changing this file
# as interfaces may have been defined in /etc/network/interfaces.d
# See LP: #1262951
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

auto enxb827eb2f0bbd
iface enxb827eb2f0bbd inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
#dns-search example.com
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254
```

I have not been able to figure out why the name wasn't set to 'eth0'. Systemd has got a proper configuration that **should** set the name to 'eth0'. Just check *'/etc/systemd/network/50-cloud-init-eth0.link'*.

I also removed

> net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0

from *'/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt'* and still it didn't work!!!

**The only way** to rename the bloody NIC was the udev way. I have reated a new file *'/etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules'* ...

> SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="b8:27:eb:2f:0b:bd",
>   NAME="net0"

Once you create this file the NIC will be called 'net0'. Obviously it is [not recommended](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Change_device_name) to use this way to rename it to 'eth0'.

But 'net0' was fine with me and I could use the new name in '/etc/network/interfaces' ...

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Source interfaces
# Please check /etc/network/interfaces.d before changing this file
# as interfaces may have been defined in /etc/network/interfaces.d
# See LP: #1262951
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

auto net0
iface net0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
#dns-search example.com
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254
```

Quite interesting to see how many different places can influence networking. But to me it also feels a bit "messy".

/Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. No Networking after a reboot, but quite often it would be ok after a total shutdown.
 This appears to be a known issue in the latest network-manager package.
 In the end I installed wicd using the instructions here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD
 All my networking issues are now resolved, except I have no network panel icon. But that's no biggy.